# Form Input Value automatically resets when executing query with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to set input field of a Modal Form using Python's Selenium

Here's how the form's input looks like :

```
<input step="any" class="input" placeholder="0" value="">
```

I set the input value with this script:

```
script = "document.querySelector("input.input").value='1'"
driver.execute_script(script)
time.sleep(3)
```

My script does enter input value in the field but it remains there only for 3 Seconds and that too due `time.sleep(3)` , otherwise it resets instantly to 0.

**How can I set it to remain there and not to reset?**

When I try normally on a HTML page, it does not resets.
It does so only on that web page.

Kindly help

Comment: Can you share the page url ?

Comment: https://zapper.fi/invest?protocol=sushiswap&contractAddress=0xe62ec2e799305e0d367b0cc3ee2cda135bf89816&modal=invest

Comment: People knowing about crypto can connect to that website and try doing this. OR try on that normal page opening with above link.

Comment: Tried it with send_keys it should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wait=WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url='https://zapper.fi/?protocol=sushiswap&contractAddress=0xe62ec2e799305e0d367b0cc3ee2cda135bf89816&modal=invest&target=%2Finvest'
driver.get(url)

elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"input")))                   
elem.send_keys('1')
```

Send keys didn't change back after a few seconds.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Outputs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine.

```
# changed it from 'input.input' -> '.input'
script = "document.querySelector('.input').value='1'"

driver.execute_script(script)
time.sleep(3)
```

Also, use single inverted commas `'` to catch the element class because you are using double inverted commas `"` to declare the script for your script variable.

When trying to catch elements by their class name to execute queries:

```
script = "document.querySelector('.class_name').value='1'"
```

When trying to catch elements by their ID to execute queries:

```
script = "document.querySelector('#ID').value='1'"
```

Alternatively, you can use the `send_keys` method too:

```
# entering the xpath of the text box you want to send your keys to
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='body']/div[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/input").send_keys("1")
```

Comment: Hi. I tried changing the script. But still the value resets automatically.

Comment: Please check the edited portion of my answer^

Comment: Tried doing this also. It still resets again.

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can set the input value and it does not resets?

Comment: Let me share you what happens

Comment: did you try the *send_keys()* method?

Comment: Yes... that doesn't works at all.

Comment: See... what happens from this gif : https://i.imgur.com/8m8iJXN.gif

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I too tried with xpath and it worked.